# Testing React/Redux with Jest advice needed

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I've been struggling for a few days writing a jest test for a React-Redux app. I'm testing one page that simply displays some account information. The page was written using a connected component with a container class. I've successfully tested if the page renders, but now I'm trying to test that it displays the correct information. It seems my main issue is troubles creating a mock store. However, I also wonder if I'm even writing the test correctly, as a lot of websites have recommended testing the mapStateToProps function (though I can't figure out how). If anyone has any advice, I'd really appreciate it!

Here is the container class:

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Account from "../components/Account";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        email: state.user.email || "",
        firstName: state.user.firstName || "",
        lastName: state.user.lastName || "",
        joined: new Date(state.user.joined).toLocaleDateString(),
    };
};

const AccountContainer = connect (mapStateToProps)(Account);

export default AccountContainer;
```

Here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import AccountContainer, {Account} from '../authed/components/Account';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import ReactSixteenAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new ReactSixteenAdapter() });

describe('Account Page Test', () => {
  const initialState = {
    email: "email@example.com",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    joined: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
  }

  const mockStore = configureStore()
  let store, container

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState)
    container = shallow(<AccountContainer store={store}/>)
  })

  test('the connected component gets rendered', () => {
    expect(container.length).toEqual(1)
  });

  test('the prop matches with initialState', () => {
    expect(container.prop('email')).toEqual(initialState.email),
    expect(container.prop('firstName')).toEqual(initialState.firstName),
    expect(container.prop('lastName')).toEqual(initialState.lastName),
    expect(container.prop('joined')).toEqual(initialState.joined),
  });
});
```

[Current Jest Results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnnd0.png)

TL;DR: I'm new to React/Redux and Jest and need help figuring out what's wrong with my test and knowing if I'm testing the right thing

Comment: PS - I do not have permissions to edit the component or container, just the test class

Comment: If you can't modify the container, then testing mapStateToProps directly would require mocking redux connect function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend the same as @Alex. To test the component separately. The approach you have taken isn't really Unit testing.

However, if you want to stick to your approach. My guess is to wrap your container with `provider` and pass the store to it will work. And you have to replace `shallow` rendering with `mount`

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import AccountContainer, {Account} from '../authed/components/Account';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import ReactSixteenAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new ReactSixteenAdapter() });

describe('Account Page Test', () => {
  const initialState = {
    email: "email@example.com",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    joined: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
  }

  const mockStore = configureStore()
  let store, container

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState)
    container = mount(<Provider store={store}>
              <AccountContainer />
            </Provider>)
  })

  test('the connected component gets rendered', () => {
    expect(container.length).toEqual(1)
  });

  test('the prop matches with initialState', () => {
    expect(container.prop('email')).toEqual(initialState.email),
    expect(container.prop('firstName')).toEqual(initialState.firstName),
    expect(container.prop('lastName')).toEqual(initialState.lastName),
    expect(container.prop('joined')).toEqual(initialState.joined),
  });
});
```

Comment: This helped a lot for the approach I had, thank you! I also discovered that the data in my initialState needed to be nested inside "user: {}". I would like to make it closer to unit testing, though, I do not have much experience so any advice would help.

Comment: In the case of unit testing, you will directly render (shallow/mount) the `Account` component and test. Your container has no logic except linking your store with the component. Unit testing implies testing only one component only. These are not the only tests that will help you to fix all problems. But these are for developers to document the behaviour of single unit (component)

Answer (score 1):

[Official docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) recommend to test **not connected component**, so in your case, you can test that `Account` component just render passed props correctly. It's much simpler then mock the store.

I.e. if `Account` is just a static container, you can test that it [matches the snapshot](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing):

```
import {Account} from '../authed/components/Account';
import * as Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ReactSixteenAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new ReactSixteenAdapter() });

describe('Account Page Test', () => {
  const initialState = {
    email: "email@example.com",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    joined: "7/12/2018",
  }

  test('the prop matches with initialState', () => {
    const tree = renderer
    .create(<Account {...initialState}>)
    .toJSON();
     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, any advice on how to do so? I was originally following [this article](https://medium.com/netscape/testing-a-react-redux-app-using-jest-and-enzyme-b349324803a9), but any helpful links you can give me would be appreciated!